# How can I make nullable string and datetime value in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing, null

```
ScdDept = fields[8] is DBNull? null:fields[8].ToString();
LeaveDate = fields[9] is DBNulL?DateTime.MaxValue:DateTime.Parse(fields[9].ToString());
```

I have A table and B table if I add some value to A table and I run my application same value added B table. But in A table LeaveDate and ScdDept is empty it looks "NULL" but B table if LeaveDate is empty it looks maksvalue and ScdDept is empty it looks empty.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `DateTime?`, presumably

Comment: What is `fields`?

Comment: This question is lacking some context. What's `fields`? what are `ScdDept` and `LeaveDate`?

Comment: I fixed and give more detailed.Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Unrelated but I would strongly advice against using strings to store date time (or any other structured data). Secondly I would advice against using plain `DateTime` (use `DateTimeOffset`) and third, since the data comes from DB and not user it means they are in uniform format, this means you need to add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to your `Parse` call to protect the code against system locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. May be `maksvalue` of your question is `MaxValue`.

> By your comment and question update I think instead of
>   `DateTime.MaxValue` of `LeaveDate` Column you want null value.

Your `LeaveDate` property should look like

```
public DateTime? LeaveDate { get; set; }
```

and then you implement like this.

```
ScdDept = fields[8] is DBNull ? null : fields[8].ToString();
LeaveDate = fields[9] is DBNull ?  (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(fields[9].ToString());
```

Comment: ScdDept is a string LeaveDate is DateTime

Comment: If ScdDept is a string then your implementation is correct because string is always nullable. If `LeaveDate` is date then DateTime.Parse would work if valid date present in fields[9]. What do you want?

Comment: I thought OP wanted a Nullable DateTime for LeaveDate?

Comment: I have a two table. İf I add a person to A table my application run an add the same person at B table. in A table SCD_DEPT and LeaveDate looks "NULL" but in B table SCD DEPT looks empty. also Leave Date Looks Maks Value I want to change it.

Comment: Do you want same value for your two tables? you want table B `LeaveDate` Null value?

Comment: I think instead of `DateTime.MaxValue` of `LeaveDate` you want null value for your `LeaveDate` column. I have updated answer.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type SystemDateTime? to System.DateTime An explicit conversion exist.

Comment: also sorry I dont know that.Iam new in C #

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** 
This will set default value if data is not parsing. It even returns whether parsing is done or not.

```
  String.TryParse( fields[8],out ScdDept );
  DateTime.TryParse(field[9],out LeaveDate );
```

**Approach 2:** 
While declaring ScdDept make it as a nullable

```
private string? ScdDept ;
private DateTime? LeaveDate ;
```

Comment: While declaring ScdDept make it as nullable

Comment: my team used: public string ScdDept { get; set; }
public DateTime LeaveDate { get; set; }

Comment: and I tried TryParse but I took an error.string does not contain a definition for tryparse also I took an error.

Comment: A property or indexer maynot be passed as an out of ref parameter also I took

Comment: @OnurcanŞimşek, then make it as a nullable. Then assign null value

Comment: @OnurcanŞimşek, U can also wrap it in private property and tryparse using private variable

Comment: How can I do actually I dont know

Comment: private string? ScdDept {get;set;}
private DateTime? LeaveDate  {get;set;}